# Visual Studio 2010 - Crash/Problems on the keyboard (Keys)

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard

Camarades,

My Visual Studio is in trouble in keyboard. I am working normally, when suddenly my keyboard loses its configuration, so where is the "" becomes "/".

Someone can tell me what would be a possible solution? (Yes, I know something is hazy).
Or has left some Pachter fix for problems like this.

Grateful for any help.
Success for all.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you accidently change keyboard input language, see [Visual Studio appears to randomly adopt American keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484248/visual-studio-appears-to-randomly-adopt-american-keyboard-layout)