# Visual Studio 2010: Editor stops responding to keyboard

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've got this very odd bug that appears to be a quirk in **Visual Studio 2010**: Sometimes, when moving the cursor into double quotes of a CSS `style=""` attribute the cursor refuses to move. I can't type anything, and the keys that respond are the `UP`/`DOWN` cursor keys and the `DEL` key (but not `BACKSPACE`).

Typing does nothing, but pushing `LEFT`/`RIGHT` on the cursor keys produces the following error:

> **The operation could not be completed**

I've got no idea what's causing this, but I would hazard a guess that **Intellisense** is getting very confused and bugging out.

At the moment, whenever this happens, I have to write any CSS outsite of the double quotes of the `style` attribute and then place the cursor where I want the CSS to appear (using the mouse) and press `CTRL`-`V` to paste it in. Very annoying :(

There must be a way of fixing this problem...?

Hopefully someone has an answer!

Comment: Never happened to me but what you could try is to turn off intellisense for css (on my older pc intellisense always slowed down or freezed VS2008.)

Comment: I've the inverse problem (and not just on CSS files) where the editor won't accecpt cursor keys, but I can type letters/numbers. Closing the reopening the file seems to be the only fix.

Comment: I've just had the same problem in .ascx and .cs files.  Backspace/Delete/Arrows not working at all.  I can type new characters okay.  Really frustrating.

Comment: @Andrew: Have you any extensions installed and enabled? Try to disable all of them and check if the problem still there. If not - try to turn them on one-by-one and thus find out who is responsible.

Comment: Mine was a new installation on a new installation of Windows 7. No extraneous extensions installed or enabled to my knowledge.

Comment: Just making sure: you do have SP1 installed, correct?

Comment: Probably you are using Reshaper. i had the same issue once i suspended reshaper worked normal without reshaper. so then i clear the reshaper cache and rebind the keyboard setting for reshaper. worked back with reshaper

Comment: Same issue with vs2013 and R# - solution from Jerry below fixes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft have had variations on this problem reported quite a few times via their support portal. [Here is one post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/665418/some-keyboard-keys-stop-working) and if you scroll down you will see a comment with a bunch of other reports all detailing similar(ish) problems.

Microsoft doesn't seem to be able to reproduce the problem but are *"duping all the similar keyboard locking problems to a central bug, so that we can think a way to log the events if necessary"*. Which seems to be a generic response to a lot of these posts. Some people reported that it was simply becuase another window/pane/tab was in focus but I can see the OP obviously did not have this specific problem. Looks to me like one of those random unresolvable bugs. Hope I never get it! There's also numerous forum posts around the Internet, where users stated that removing certain 3rd party plugins has solved this issue.

I just spotted [this particular post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616775/certain-keyboard-keys-stop-working-when-using-vs2010) which has a possibly useful comment on it for you (which also link to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484248/visual-studio-appears-to-randomly-adopt-american-keyboard-layout). As I do not have the bug I cannot test its validity for you. The main point of it seems to be something about the keyboard layout switching.

I'm sorry for putting all this into an answer when technically it is not an answer and just a mass of research, but there was no way this was gonna fit into a comment. And also sorry for pretty much link spamming, but again there was no way I could extract *everything* that they said into this post. I hope there is something useful in there for you :)

---

EDIT: You should probably check the top rated answer below as this seems to solve a number of peoples issues, although I never had the Resharper plugin and still occasionally experienced this, but now I'm on VS2013 and have not had this problem re-occur, so maybe they fixed it...

Comment: How can they not duplicate this. All you have to do is use Visual Studio. It happens all the time. Very annoying.

Comment: See response from [Erez Cohen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22457449/779521) below. Seems like this is in very many cases due to a problem with the Resharper add-in.

Answer (score 54):

Just encountered the issue in VS 2012, in editing C#.
I noticed that the problem had occurred soon after the trial period of Resharper has ended and i inserted a valid license number. It also happened in only some of the source files.
The solution: **Tools->Options->Resharper: Suspend.**
Try typing - should work now.
Then: **Tools->Options->Resharper: Resume.**
Problem gone.

Comment: Reinstalling Resharper helped for me (with update to 8.2.1 version).

Comment: Resharper was causing my issue, and Jerry's solution below was what helped me.

Comment: Reported to JetBrains. Link here - http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/requests/10752

Comment: Suspend-Resume ReSharper did not helped. ReSharper Options - Environment -  General - Clear Caches solved problem

Comment: This fixed my issue today. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

I have encountered this using Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8.2.1. None of the solutions provided in this thread worked (even suspending and resuming Resharper)

After contacting JetBrains support, it turned out to be a caching issue.

Deleting all the files from the following directory solved the issue, as Resharper re-creates new caches:

```
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\[Project_reference]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had the issue in Visual Studio 2012 and deleting that cache folder solved it.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue after creating a new project and wanting to type something in right away. Deleting the cache has helped.

Comment: A BIG thank's for this. Had this same issue and appeared out of nowhere.

Answer (score 24):

I have some odd issues with the editor occasionally, a workaround for me is:

Ctrl-Tab (x2) to another code file and back to the same code (or alt tab to another app and back, one of these two... can't replicate issue to be sure)

An ultimate solution might be a re-install.

Comment: AFAIK, re-install will not help. VS2010 is a buggy product.

Comment: Sometimes I cannot ctrl-tab, but in that case clicking on another tab and back resolves the issue.

Answer (score 13):

**Empty the solution cache folder**

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\
```

This was suggested by [JetBrains support](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/96181906-Unable-to-edit-most-of-files-in-a-certain-solution-with-ReSharper-enabled) when I contacted them.

Comment: This was also the solution for me.

Comment: This has consistently fixed the problem for me whenever this issue pops up. Except I went 'Resharper > Options > General' and clicked the 'Clear Cache' button, then closed and reopened VS.

Answer (score 6):

Permanently fixing... Not too sure however I found that pressing pressing Ctrl+Shift+Caps Lock+Tab all at once seems to get rid of this and enables the mouse and keyboard again. I know this isn't the best of solutions but it works.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem several times a day.  I didn't notice it until I installed the web essentials extension.  I just uninstalled it and will see what happens.  I have tried reinstalling visual studio with no joy (but again, I didn't notice the problem until after I had already installed the various extensions).

Sometimes, closing and re-opening the specific code window I'm working in fixes it.  If that fails, sometimes I close all windows and reopen just the one I was actively editing.  If all of that fails it usually requires a complete restart of visual studio.

I find it funny that MSFT says that they can't duplicate the problem.  Scott Guthrie experienced it first hand during his MVC4 beta demo [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2364) at about 28 minutes in.

**UPDATE:**  So far, as of 4-5-2012 9:33am Central Time, the problem hasn't recurred since uninstalling Web Essentials.  This is the longest I've gone without this bug occurring.  If I make it through the next 24 hours, I'll be confident in blaming Web Essentials.

**UPDATE:**  4-6-2012 10:05am Central Time:  Well, apparently it wasn't Web Essentials.  It happened to me again this morning editing the contents of a  block in my _Layout.vbhtml file.  Closing the tab and reopening it fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I frequently encounter this editor freeze, not just on CSS quotes but any file arbitrarily. I have a dual monitor setp and I have the doucment windows one one monitor and all tool windows on the next one. Sometimes, certain tool windows would freeze too (i.e. not respond to click).

Previously, I used to shutdown/restart IDE; but serendipitously, I discovered that switching to/from Full Screen mode, restores sanity. So now everytme I see a freeze, mode switching comes to rescue.

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but worth a shot.

Rant: In general, I find this new WPF based product very falky and unstable than its predeccessors.

Comment: While editing C# and/or TypeScript source files, I started experiencing my keyboard intermittently locking up with **Visual Studio 2019** version 16.8.x. Upgrading to version 16.9.1 has not resolved the problem. However, as you have suggested, switching to **Full Screen mode** and back has restored my keyboard. (From the near the bottom of the **View** menu, select **Full Screen**, or enter **Shift+Alt+Enter**.)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem on IDE, some times the Return key is not working at all... 
My solution is: CLEAN the project/solution.

BTW: CLEANing resolve also other unexpected behaviours after amendements on CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I tried every other workaround here but nothing seemed to work, and the issue was only present in one solution but not another.

Disabling Resharper fixed it temporarily but it came back after re-enabling it which wasn't a viable long-term solution.

What worked for me was disabling all Resharper Extensions (Under Resharper -> Extension Manager).  I was able to type again even after re-enabling all of them, so I'm unsure which extension specifically caused the issue, but that's another route to try for people who still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I never had the problem until I installed plugins/extensions.  Curious to know if anyone has had this problem without having any plugins/extensions installed.  I don't know if they are the actual cause but since benefits of the plugins outweigh the occasional lockup, I have left them installed.  BTW, I use the "closing/reopening of the window with the lockup" technique.

Answer (score -1):

Using a source control (GIT, AKSVN)? If so, disable it, restart VS then enable it and open the solution again.