# Visual Studio locks Control, Shift, Alt keys while developing XAML / WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, ide

While using Visual Studio I occasionally experience odd input 'quirks.' Certain types of input don't get through to the editor, while others do. It seems linked to one of the modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift) becoming 'locked' and causing the input to get routed in an alternate manner.

It occurs, almost exclusively, while I'm editing a WPF control's XAML. There are always multiple VS workspaces open across multiple monitors, but I'm not sure if that is linked to the issue, since that is a near-constant attribute of my development.

When the issue occurs, I can sometimes change window focus, save-all open files, and/or minimize all VS windows to resolve; although occasionally none of these work and I must completely restart VS.

I've turned Windows Sticky Keys off (although I was sure I wasn't toggling them), but that did not resolve the issue.

Similar question: [Visual Studio 2010: Editor stops responding to keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310033/visual-studio-2010-editor-stops-responding-to-keyboard)

Comment: Shut down VS and restarting it is the only thing that works for me.  This happens to me in MVC .asax files too.  It happened to Scott Guthrie while he was presenting in Europe earlier this year - he had to restart VS.

Comment: Hitting alt-enter (you may need to select an item in the solution explorer) has worked for me in similar situations.  Give it a shot next time it crops up.

Comment: When I hit the "omg the ctrl key is locked on", I've had good luck whacking Ctrl-Break and Esc (separately) a couple of times.

Comment: What a cluster of a bug. No seemingly constant entry point, a bevy of 'resolutions,' and rather drastic effects on productivity. I've now found that switching to another window, or code file, and typing 'asdf', hitting ctrl, alt, shift in that order, non-concurrent, pressing home once, and delete four times has served me well in regaining dominance over my keyboards input. 

It also has the added, unintended benefit of giving me unlimited memory and access to all .DLLs ever compiled! 
U, D, U, D, L, R, L, R, Select, Start!