# SQL Server 2005 typing # in query produces \

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm sure this is a really simple issue but when I'm working in SQL Server 2005 sometimes when I type '#' it instead produces '\'

Is there anything I can do to stop this? I've tried working out what seems to trigger it but I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Thanks :)

Comment: I sometimes found that unaccountably SSMS 2005 would change to the US keyboard layout whilst other applications (e.g. notepad) were unaffected. Closing and reopening SSMS seemed to sort it out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484248/visual-studio-appears-to-randomly-adopt-american-keyboard-layout

Comment: Fantastic - tried searching for dupe question and couldn't find it - bizarrely only works for the right shift key on the keyboard! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this as an issue in SSMS and Visual Studio both. It seems to happen after keeping the application open for an extended period of time. Closing and reopening usually resolves the problem.