# Ctrl+Space changes keyboard instead of showing Intellisense's Auto-complete list on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, layout, keyboard, space, ctrl

I noticed that unexpectedly Visual Studio 2010 changed the keyboard layout.I tried some solutions like:

```
- Going to Windows' Control Panel and removing other languages
- Going to Menu Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings and set the Language as "Same as Microsoft Windows"
- Going to Menu Tools > Options > Text Editor > All languages and check whether the Statement completion's "Auto list members" option was checked or not
```

for correcting this issue.

After some days of huge irritation, I finally discovered when this situation was happening: It is when a person types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, which is supposed to show Intellisense's Auto-complete, not to change keyboard layout.

So, please help me if you have a solution

EDIT: I didn't discover yet any solution unless restarting Visual Studio for getting back to my homeland keyboard. After some more editing, I think I am beginning to decorate the US keyboard layout and adapting myself to it.

Comment: Seems to me that after I rebooted the Windows Operating System, now everything works correctly, so I am assuming that the answer is one of the solutions previously referred and it implicates restarting to make effect.

Answer (score 3):

Returning to this topic as I had the same problem. Namely, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> did NOT fire intellisense or autocomplete, but instead just permanently changed the keyboard layout that couldn't be changed back again unless I restarted VS2010. Tried quite a few solutions myself without results.

I finally got it working by erasing all other language settings from Windows save for Finnish. Then restarted VS2010 and voilá, haven't seen the problem since.

Changing keyboard language priority to Finnish in Windows didn't help, I had to delete all the other installed language settings. Also, changing the settings from VS2010 to use Windows settings for keyboard layout didn't help at all either.

And the problem was never the wrong shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> was always mapped for intellisense / autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is wondering, just press Alt+Shift and it will change the keyboard language. I guess I often pressed this key-combo and did't know what was happening.

Comment: I press it quite often for doing "rectangular selection".

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] What I was checking was Tools->Options->Keyboard, thinking someone accidentally remapped to an earlier version but after some checking, Ctrl-Space was always Complete Word going back to VB6 so I doubt that was it.

Still, it should say 'Default' in there.  You could always try resetting it as well but I don't think it's going to be your solution.

Answer (score 1):

i used to have this problem what i simply did is

control panel -> region and language ->(you will get a new popup window)keyboards and languages tab -> change keyboards button -> (again new pop-up window)General tab -> in the installed services->remove all the languages except your own language -> save

done now intellisense will work since no more keyboard layout is found

Hope this helped someone :)

Answer (score 0):

The problematic component can be Microsoft Pinyin.  I got it as a part of Microsoft Office Proofing Tools. From time time it starts stealing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and switching keyboard layout to Simplified Chinese/Korean etc.

It can be removed from add/remove programs -> Microsoft Office Proofing Tools -> Change...

Answer (score 0):

**Reboot was required**

This is one of the absolutely most annoying problems you can come across in Visual Studio 2010.

Every time I hit the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> VS 2010 would change the keyboard layout. It changed from Norwegian to English. The change is only inside Visual Studio, the Language Bar still shows Norwegian. I had Norwegian and English keyboards installed. Norwegian first, that's what I use.

The only thing that was able to reset the keyboard was a restart of Visual Studio. But the next time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get AutoCompletion the layout changed again. It only affects Visual Studio.

I tried the following:

1. Checked key-mappings for switching keyboard layout. I had cleared those long ago.
2. Deleted the English keyboard (only the Norwegian one left).
3. Tried changing the Language under Tools - Options - International Settings.
4. Deleted the .suo file.
5. Deleted the .sdf file (since the problem was related to IntelliSense)
6. I also tried every imaginable keyboard combination (many suggested in different forums), but none of them worked.

In between all of these I restarted Visual Studio, but to no avail.

The problem only went away when I restarted my computer. I suspect that deleting the English keyboard did the trick, but that a reboot is required.

I am on Windows 7. My solution contains C# class libraries as well as C++/CLI class libraries.

Comment: sidenote: @Abhisek I'm currently rejecting some of your edits as they don't improve the question enough. Please make sure you only fix posts that need fixing and if you do fix everything.