# Visual Studio 2013 changes the keyboard language

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-layout

I'm using German keyboard layout and English Windows 8.1. However, Visual Studio 2013 keeps changing the keyboard layout to the English ones. I can't even predict when it changes it. It's pretty random.

**Question:** Why does Visual Studio do this and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bytecode77,

The shortcuts you are pressing in VS must be coinciding with the Windows shortcuts for changing language. This is why it seems random to you.

I think that your question is answered in more detail here:

[Visual Studio appears to randomly adopt American keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484248/visual-studio-appears-to-randomly-adopt-american-keyboard-layout)

and here:
[Ctrl+Space changes keyboard instead of showing Intellisense's Auto-complete list on Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951960/ctrlspace-changes-keyboard-instead-of-showing-intellisenses-auto-complete-list)

Comment: You're right. And unassigning the hotkeys for it works just fine. No one needs them anyway.