# ReSharper blocks keyboard input in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

Recently my Visual Studio 2013 stopped responding to keyboard input. I couldn't type anything in any of the files. I suspended ReSharper and It worked again but I would really want to use ReSharper. I tried reinstalling ReSharper but without success. I can't seem to find a solution for this problem. It occured after the weekend and it worked perfectly before.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this issue before with certain Resharper plugins (in my case Stylecop) that were built for a different version of the Resharper / Visual Studio / StyleCop version.

Comment: Well the weird part is everything worked before the weekend and then tuesday when I came back to work it broke down.

Comment: Also happened on Visual Studio 2012. Much thanks for an easy solution.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Clean the following folder with ReSharper caches `C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\`

**[Update]**
For R# 9.x/10.x: `%LocalAppData%\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs{VS version}\v0{some digit depends on R# version}`

Comment: Wow - thanks!  would never have found it and it was driving me crazy

Comment: There is also a button "Clear Caches" in ReSharper (v8.2) Options under Environment -> General, section "Caches (effective on solution open/close)".
That should clear the same files as Alexander mentioned in his answer. Additionally you can change the path/folder where the caches are stored.

Comment: Oh... It does not help me(((

Comment: Hard to believe JetBrains can't fix this. I thought I was going mad and couldn't believe it when this hit came up in Google.

Comment: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104588-Unable-to-edit-most-of-files-in-a-certain-solution-with-ReSharper-enabled

Comment: @Alexander Kurakin - Many blessings be upon you. My keyboard was responding, but I could not modify any of my source files in my project, although I could modify my `Miscellaneous Files`. My cache is in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches`, and I simply removed the subdirectory for my particular project `_ReSharper.{ProjectName}.-{nnnnnnnnn}`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try (- within SSMS), clicking upon the `Tools` menu, clicking the `Customize` option, clicking the `Keyboard` button, and then clicking the `Reset` button, in order to reset/fix the key-bindings.

It worked for me, for both v16.5.3 and v17.5. I have RSharper installed / no R#er changes necessary.