# Problems with writing ( in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I suddenly cannot make this " ( " starting bracket symbol in eclipse anymore.

It works fine in all other programs, but not in eclipse. How can i enable it again?

Comment: Check .metadata/.log in your workspace. Something might be crashing (e.g. code assist, parentheses auto-close, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard shortcut mistakenly defined? Or other config problem. Have you been changing keyboard shortcuts recently? I'd expect that with a fresh install of Eclipse, the ( bracket key will work fine.

Another possibility is that some badly-written content-type editor is parsing & crashing on the (..  could be possible, though Eclipse isn't generally structured this way. Try closing the file/resource and opening it as "text".

Or, as @Lasse_Christiansen says -- accidental input-language change.

Answer (score 2):

Have you shut down Eclipse and restarted it? I've noticed that Eclipse has some strange issues that are solved by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

What about the input language/keyboard layout - have you checked that it matches what you expect? Sometimes, you accidentally hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> on Windows, and it changes the input language causing these "silly" errors - an example includes a previous question at StackOverflow targeting Visual Studio: [Visual Studio appears to randomly adopt American keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484248/visual-studio-appears-to-randomly-adopt-american-keyboard-layout).